# postgreql : how to do query "case when ... else nothing"

Tags: postgresql

I have a column `category` and there are 3 values possible "pos", "neg" and "zero".

I am looking for a query that shows POSITIVE when it's pos, NEGATIVE when it's neg and nothing when it's zero.

With my query below, I get null when its zero. Is there any way to not select zero?

```
SELECT distinct(category),
case when nature='POS' then 'POSITIVE'
     when nature='NEG' then 'NEGATIVE'
end as category_rm
FROM table_h;
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT** a function `distinct (a), b` is exactly the same as `distinct a, (b)` or `distinct a,b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `else` in the case expression as `else 'zero'`, so it will return `zero` for the not matching `POS` and `NEG` values.

```
SELECT distinct category,
       case when nature = 'POS' then 'POSITIVE'
            when nature = 'NEG' then 'NEGATIVE'
            else 'zero'  
       end as category_rm
FROM table_h;
```

> Is there any way to not select zero?

If so avoid it in the `WHERE` clause as

```
SELECT distinct category,
       case when nature = 'POS' then 'POSITIVE'
            when nature = 'NEG' then 'NEGATIVE'
       end as category_rm
FROM table_h
WHERE nature != 'zero';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your second query is what I was searching for!